# bundling js files with browserify through npm script from package.json

Tags: angularjs, npm, browserify, bundling-and-minification

This is for bundling JS files through Browserify with out Grunt/Gulp . but through npm script(defined in package.json)

I am working on Anularjs mature application. which have everything in it.
right now its using grunt for bundling all js files and then refers that bundle file to index.html page.

i couldnt find any article which can let me know how can i user browserify for bundling all the js files (**with minimum changes**)of my project.

Folder structure of Project.

[image: Folder structure of the project]

or can someone please share any good article on it.

Thanks in advance.